# How to set severityOverrides in lintOptions?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project defining

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Android plugin for gradle
        // http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // ...
```

In my app I want to set

```
android {
    // ...

    lintOptions {
        // http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/1.5/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions:severityOverrides
        severityOverrides {
            ["MissingTranslation": "warning"]
        }

        // ...
```

but I get the error

> Error:(34, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'severityOverrides()'
>   Possible causes: The project 'android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

What is the correct way to set [severityOverrides](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/1.5/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions:severityOverrides)?

---

Versions that did compile but do not have the desired effect on the `:app:lintVitalRelease` build step:

```
import com.android.builder.model.LintOptions
// ...
severityOverrides ["MissingTranslation": LintOptions.SEVERITY_WARNING]
```

and

```
import com.android.builder.model.LintOptions
// ...
severityOverrides.MissingTranslation = LintOptions.SEVERITY_WARNING
```

Comment: which version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: @JBaruch Version 2.10 set in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: The docs you linked says the type should be a map of string and integer, so the second value should be an integer, or more appropriately an enum from some class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would like to share what I'm doing.

Instead of set severityOverrides, you can call one method to each type of flag that you want to set.

```
lintOptions {
    ignore "RtlEnabled", "RtlHardcoded", "RtlSymmetry" ....
    warning "RtlEnabled", "RtlHardcoded", "RtlSymmetry" ....
    error "RtlEnabled", "RtlHardcoded", "RtlSymmetry" ....
    fatal "RtlEnabled", "RtlHardcoded", "RtlSymmetry" ....
    informational "RtlEnabled", "RtlHardcoded", "RtlSymmetry" ....
}
```

In your case, you can do:

```
lintOptions {
    warning "MissingTranslation"
}
```

I'm not sure if you can manually set severityOverrides since it is a read only property.

So, I think you really must call one of the methods above (error, fatal etc..) to override the property that you want

Comment: Agree with vRallev

Answer (score 3):

(Not an answer-answer, but this is what I used as an equivalent replacement when I couldn't get `lintOptions.severityOverrides` to work)

Drop a lint.xml file with the same configuration at the root of the module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<lint>
    <issue id="MissingTranslation" severity="warning" />
</lint>
```

You also get a richer API to tune lint warnings through `lint.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

> `Map<String, Integer> severityOverrides`

The documents you linked to say that the type for severityOverrides should be `Map<String, Integer>` where as you're using two strings. Also, severityOverrides doesn't seem to be a method but a property instead, so you should leave out the curly braces `{}` Which gives you:

```
import com.android.builder.model.LintOptions
lintOptions {
    severityOverrides ["MissingTranslation": LintOptions.SEVERITY_WARNING]
}
```

Comment: The error remains the same. Is setting via `{ [ ... ] }` even correct? Is severityOverrides a "method"? When I use `severityOverrides = ["MissingTranslation": LintOptions.SEVERITY_WARNING]` I get *Error:(37, 0) Could not find property 'LintOptions' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions_Decorated@f8baf33.*

Comment: Not a method, I would leave out the `{}`. You might also have to import `LintOptions` or use the fully qualified name.

Comment: `com.android.builder.model.LintOptions.SEVERITY_WARNING`

Comment: Okay, now the SEVERITY_WARNING integer is available. I needed to add a `=` to assign the property severityOverrides. But now I get *Error:(39, 0) Cannot set the value of read-only property 'severityOverrides' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions_Decorated@45a37591.*

Comment: If set doesn't work, add might. try `severityOverrides << [... , ...]`

Comment: Now it compiles but has no effect. The gradle build step `:app:lintVitalRelease` still fails because of missing translations. What is the `<<` operator doing exactly?

Comment: `<<` is groovy shorthand for append to collection.

Comment: see: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/04/groovy-goodness-adding-maps-to-map_21.html

Comment: And from that link it seems like the prop key is not enclosed in quotes? Shot in the dark, can you please try `severityOverrides << [MissingTranslation: LintOptions.SEVERITY_WARNING]` (No quotes around `MissingTranslation`

Comment: That compiles as good as with quotes. But the result remains the same: *18 errors, 0 warnings* in `:app:lintVitalRelease` when building an APK.

Comment: I'll take a look at the lint options dsl code, but I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Comment: `severityOverrides.MissingTranslation = LintOptions.SEVERITY_WARNING` does also compile. But the effect remains the same as before.

Comment: BTW, how are you running your Lint task? From the commandline or from Android Studio?

Comment: From Android Studio: either "Generate Signed APK" or build variant "release" + "Build APK"

Answer (score 0):

just try as followed

```
lintOptions {
    severityOverrides
    ["HardcodedText": LintOptions.SEVERITY_ERROR
     , 'SetTextI18n': LintOptions.SEVERITY_ERROR]

    checkReleaseBuilds true
    abortOnError true
    check 'HardcodedText', 'SetTextI18n'

}
```